# Rearranging symbolic expression

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, mupad

I have a function in MuPAD in terms of various variables as `z = f(x,y,...)`.
Now I would like to rearrange the equation to express `x` in terms of `z`. I have not found the suitable command to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `solve`. Example:

```
syms x y z
X = solve('z = x^3 + y^3 - 1', x);
```

Comment: I tried solve. It gives me four different answers subject to different conditions. I was assuming there would be a simpler solution to this closed form equation.

Comment: You can set constraints for the variables, for example: `syms y positive`, this may shorten the result. You can add `'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints', true` to the parameter list of `solve`, and you will get simplified results.